# How to sort an array from the smallest element to the biggest (like 1 to 10 ) and to show the number of iterations and the number of comparisons

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

So, I have this code which sorts an array by 5 methods bubble sort, insertion, shell, quicksort, and selection. I also need it to sort the array from the smallest element to the biggest  (like 1 to 10 ) and to show the number of iterations and the number of comparisons but I can't find a method to do so.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int a[10000],b[10000];
long int c[5],k;
float d[5];

float B(int t)
{
    clock_t me,ti;
    int aux,i,j;
    float w;
    me=clock();

    for(i=1;i<t;i++)
        for(j=i;j>0;j--)
        if(a[j]<a[j-1])
        {
            aux=a[j];
            a[j]=a[j-1];
            a[j-1]=aux;
            k++;
        }

    ti=clock();
    w=(float)(ti-me)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return w;
}

float I(int t)
{
    clock_t me,ti;
    int aux,i,j;
    float w;
    me=clock();

    for(i=0;i<t-1;i++)
        for(j=1;j<t-i;j++)
            if(a[i+j]<a[i])
            {
                aux=a[i];
                a[i]=a[i+j];
                a[i+j]=aux;
                k++;
            }

    ti=clock();
    w=(float)(ti-me)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return w;
}

float S(int t)
{
    clock_t me,ti;
    int i,j,min,lm;
    float w;
    me=clock();

    for(i=0;i<t-1;i++)
    {
        min=a[i];lm=i;
        for(j=i+1;j<t;j++)
            if(a[j]<min)
            {
                min=a[j];
                lm=j;
            }
            a[lm]=a[i];
            a[i]=min;
            k++;
    }

    ti=clock();
    w=(float)(ti-me)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return w;
}

float Sh(int t)
{
    clock_t me,ti;
    int aux,i,j,pas;
    float w;
    me=clock();

    for(pas=t/2;pas>0;pas/=2)
        for(i=pas;i<t;i++)
            for(j=i-pas;j>=0&&a[j]>a[j+pas];j-=pas)
            {
                aux=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+pas];
                a[j+pas]=aux;
                k++;
            }

    ti=clock();
    w=(float)(ti-me)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    return w;
}

void Q(int v,int t)
{
    int i,j;
    float aux,x;
    x=a[v];
    i=v;
    j=t;

    while(i<j)
    {
        while(a[i]<=x&&i<t)
            i++;
        while(a[j]>x)
            j--;
        if(i<j)
        {
            aux=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=aux;
            k++;
        }
    }

    if(j>v)
    {
        a[v]=a[j];
        a[j]=x;
        k++;
    }

    if(v<j-1)
        Q(v,j-1);
    if(t>j+1)
        Q(j+1,t);
}

int main()
{
    int al,i,n;
    clock_t me,ti;

    printf("Select array size...\n");
    printf("\t1. 100 elements.\n");
    printf("\t2. 1000 elements.\n");
    printf("\t3. 10000 elements.\n");
    printf("\t0. Close the programm.\n");
    printf("Your choise is ");
    scanf("%i",&al);

    switch(al)
    {
        case 1 :
            n=100;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=-99+rand()/(RAND_MAX/(99-(-99)+1)+1);

            printf("\nInitial array...\n");

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                printf("%4i ",a[i]);
            printf("\n");

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                b[i]=a[i];

            k=0;
            d[0]=B(n);
            c[0]=k;
            printf("\nArray sorted with bubblesort...\n");

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                printf("%4i ",a[i]);
            printf("\n\n");

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=b[i];

            k=0;
            d[1]=I(n);
            c[1]=k;

            printf("Array sorted with insertion...\n");
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                printf("%4i ",a[i]);
            printf("\n\n");

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=b[i];

            k=0;
            d[2]=S(n);
            c[2]=k;

            printf("Array sorted with selection...\n");
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                printf("%4i ",a[i]);
            printf("\n\n");

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=b[i];

            k=0;
            d[3]=Sh(n);
            c[3]=k;

            printf("Arrau sorted with shell...\n");
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                printf("%4i ",a[i]);
            printf("\n\n");

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=b[i];

            k=0;
            me=clock();
            Q(0,n-1);
            ti=clock();
            d[4]=(float)(ti-me)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            c[4]=k;

            printf("Array sorted with quicksort...\n");
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                printf("%4i ",a[i]);
            printf("\n\n");

            printf("\t      Results...\n");
            printf("\t|=============|============|=================|\n");
            printf("\t|  Name       |   Time     | Nr of changes   |\n");
            printf("\t|=============|============|=================|\n");
            printf("\t| Bubble sort |  %f  |      %5li      |\n",d[0],c[0]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            printf("\t| Insertion   |  %f  |      %5li      |\n",d[1],c[1]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            printf("\t| Selection   |  %f  |      %5li      |\n",d[2],c[2]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            printf("\t|   Shell     |  %f  |      %5li      |\n",d[3],c[3]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            printf("\t| Quicksort   |  %f  |      %5li      |\n",d[4],c[4]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            break;

         case 2 :
            n=1000;

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=-99+rand()/(RAND_MAX/(99-(-99)+1)+1);

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                b[i]=a[i];

            k=0;
            d[0]=B(n);
            c[0]=k;

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=b[i];

            k=0;
            d[1]=I(n);
            c[1]=k;

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=b[i];

            k=0;
            d[2]=S(n);
            c[2]=k;

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=b[i];

            k=0;
            d[3]=Sh(n);
            c[3]=k;

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=b[i];

            k=0;
            me=clock();
            Q(0,n-1);
            ti=clock();
            d[4]=(float)(ti-me)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            c[4]=k;

            printf("\t      Results...\n");
            printf("\t|=============|============|=================|\n");
            printf("\t|  Name       |   Time     | Nr of changes   |\n");
            printf("\t|=============|============|=================|\n");
            printf("\t| Bubble sort |  %f  |      %7li      |\n",d[0],c[0]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            printf("\t| Insertion   |  %f  |      %7li      |\n",d[1],c[1]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            printf("\t| Selection   |  %f  |      %7li      |\n",d[2],c[2]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            printf("\t|   Shell     |  %f  |      %7li      |\n",d[3],c[3]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            printf("\t| Quicksort   |  %f  |      %7li      |\n",d[4],c[4]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            break;

         case 3 :
            n=10000;

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=-99+rand()/(RAND_MAX/(99-(-99)+1)+1);
            for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
                b[i]=a[i];

            k=0;
            d[0]=B(n);
           c[0]=k;

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=b[i];

            k=0;
            d[1]=I(n);
            c[1]=k;

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=b[i];

            k=0;
            d[2]=S(n);
            c[2]=k;

            for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
                a[i]=b[i];

            k=0;
            d[3]=Sh(n);
            c[3]=k;

            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                a[i]=b[i];

            k=0;
            me=clock();
            Q(0,n-1);
            ti=clock();
            d[4]=(float)(ti-me)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            c[4]=k;

            printf("\t      Results...\n");
            printf("\t|=============|============|=================|\n");
            printf("\t|  Name       |   Time     | Nr of changes   |\n");
            printf("\t|=============|============|=================|\n");
            printf("\t| Bubble sort |  %f  |      %9li      |\n",d[0],c[0]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            printf("\t| Insertion   |  %f  |      %9li      |\n",d[1],c[1]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            printf("\t| Selection   |  %f  |      %9li      |\n",d[2],c[2]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            printf("\t|   Shell     |  %f  |      %9li      |\n",d[3],c[3]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            printf("\t| Quicksort   |  %f  |      %9li      |\n",d[4],c[4]);
            printf("\t|-------------|------------|-----------------|\n");
            break;

        case 0:
            printf("\n!You closed the programm.\n");
            break;

        default:
            printf("\n!Error!\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I only want to know what must be added.

Comment: You need to modify the sort functions so that they record the wanted data as they proceed.  There are many ways in which the details could be implemented.  You cannot readily do the job by observing the functions externally.